# External Link from Featured Image- Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How would I add a custom meta box to my Wordpress theme that allows users to add a link to an external page from the featured image? I have a slider set up that pulls featured images from a custom post type and I'd like to be able to add an external link from that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box